# Why Does My Image Overlap My Banner

Tags: image, css, html

here is my JsFiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J35sf/)

i want to know why my image/image caption overlap's my website banner? I'm pretty sure its something to do with my absolute positioning but I'm not 100% sure! I'm trying to have the image/image caption right under the banner. I don't want to position it with px/cm/in because it may be different across screen sizes!

Html:

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<body>
    <div class="banner"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7m4rahc.jpg" alt="Loading..."/></div>

    <div id="mainwrapper">

        <div id="box-3" class="box">  
            <img id="image-3" src="http://i.imgur.com/NEZfdM7.jpg"/>  
            <span class="caption fade-caption">  
                <h3>Click To Subscribe</h3>  
                <center>
                    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

                    <div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="AfterlifeGamingHD" data-layout="full" data-count="default"></div>
                </center>  
            </span>  
        </div>  

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/2MVANTR.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img, .banner {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
#mainwrapper .box {  

    border: 5px solid #fff;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    float: left;  
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    width: 370px;  
    height: 470px;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;  
}  

#mainwrapper .box img {  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    width: 370px;  
    height: 470px;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}
#mainwrapper .box .caption {  
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);  
    position: absolute;  
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    left: 0;  
}
#mainwrapper .box .fade-caption, #mainwrapper .box .scale-caption {  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 370px;  
    height: 470px;  
    text-align: left;  
    padding: 15px;  
}  
#mainwrapper .box:hover .fade-caption {  
    opacity: 1;  
}
```

Comment: apply `z-index: -1;` to your image. Not really sure what you want though

Comment: @marczking for the image to be below the banner, not with a z-index

Comment: oh, I read `below` as `underneath`, that's why I was confused ^^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` removes an element from the document flow, allowing other elements to take up the freed space. There seems to be no real reason for you using `position: absolute`, so just remove it...

Comment: it looks strange in Dreamweaver if i remove it, but if it works ill accept it.

Comment: Protip: Don't use Dreamweaver, it's not worth it! :p

Comment: -prolonged silence as I sit here, silently judging you for your brazenness-

Comment: i feel dumb for not thinking of such a simple thing xD thanks anyways!

Comment: Everything looks weird in DreamWeaver, but you could 'Preview in *webbrowser*' or select Live view. Dreamweaver just simulates how it would look like on a browser, but it's simulation is (obviously) very poor. Yet DreamWeaver is very useful for it's automatically tag closing and built-in FTP Client.

Comment: @DaanHeskes Notepad++ has much more than Dreamweaver and is free :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol DreamWeaver has much more than Notepad++, I also use Notepad++ because I hate DreamWeaver, yet it's better because it is a text editor with a built-in FTP Client.

Comment: @DaanHeskes NP++ gets plugins. I have NppFTP right now connected to my dev server.

Answer (score 0):

```
#box-3{
position:relative;
top:500px;(set this to what you want it)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J35sf/5/

You could just position it to where ever you want it. :)